# haproxy: Can I annotate an IP whitelist file?

Tags: configuration, haproxy

In my "/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg" file, I specify a whitelist file that contains IP addresses that are permitted to access a frontend.

```
frontend default-frontend
    <snip>

    tcp-request connection reject if ! { src -f /etc/haproxy/templates/ip-whitelist.txt }

    <snip>
```

The contents of "/etc/haproxy/templates/ip-whitelist.txt" look like this:

```
192.45.21.89/32
123.34.33.7/32
56.23.12.77/32
78.12.66.3/32
```

This works great! Until I want to clean up the file and remove IPs for people who no longer need access.

***Question*: Is it possible to add comments to an `haproxy` template file?**

I have tried this:

```
192.45.21.89/32 # Dylan Reeve
123.34.33.7/32 # Jane Doe
56.23.12.77/32 # Priscilla Ahmed
78.12.66.3/32 # Sayed Salas
```

... which returns errors similar to:

```
[ALERT] : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:123] : 'tcp-request connection reject' :
    error detected in frontend 'default-frontend' while parsing 'if' condition : 
    '192.45.21.89/32 # Dylan Reeve' is not a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address
    at line 1 of file '/etc/haproxy/templates/ip-whitelist.txt'
[ALERT] : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] : Fatal errors found in configuration.
```

Worst case scenario: I have to keep separate list in another location to match IPs with names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [HAProxy v1.8 documentation](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#7), this should work:

```
# Dylan Reeve
192.45.21.89/32
# Jane Doe
123.34.33.7/32
...
```

Taken from 1.8 docs (I've been doing this on 1.6 as well):

> The "-f" flag is followed by the name of a file from which all lines
>   will be read as individual values. It is even possible to pass
>   multiple "-f" arguments if the patterns are to be loaded from multiple
>   files. **Empty lines as well as lines beginning with a sharp ('#')
>   will be ignored.** All leading spaces and tabs will be stripped.
>   If it is absolutely necessary to insert a valid pattern beginning with
>   a sharp, just prefix it with a space so that it is not taken for a
>   comment.

Or you could try using [HAProxy maps](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/introduction-to-haproxy-maps/) which I think are complete overkill for your use case.

Comment: That did it. Thank you. Just an extra note, apparently haproxy also does not like any whitespace, other than a newline, after an ip address on the same line.